# Applying function to cartesian product of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have two lists

```
X = {1, 2, 3};
Y = {5, 6, 7, 8};
```

I want to apply function `g[x,y_,z_]` to all pairs from X*Y, so I need to get a list `{g[x,1,5],g[x,1,6]…,g[x,3,8]}`

I came up with this syntax

```
g[x, ##] &@(Sequence @@ #) & /@ Tuples[{X, Y}]
```

and it gives what I want.

Is there more elegant way to do it?

**Update:** The most elegant way is proposed by *belisarius*:

```
f[1, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{x, y}]
```

I compared performance of three methods

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
bel[x_, y_] := f[1, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{x, y}];
mar[x_, y_] := Flatten[Outer[f[1, ##] &, x, y]];
bkow[x_, y_] := f[1, ##] &@(Sequence @@ #) & /@ Tuples[{x, y}];

benchmark[f_, n_] := 
  Module[{l = Range[1, n]}, 
   Mean@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[f[l, l]], {20}]];

TableForm[
   Table[benchmark[fun, n]/n/n, {fun, {bel, mar, bkow}}, {n, #}], 
   TableHeadings -> {{"bel", "mar", "bkow"}, #}] &@{10, 30, 100, 300, 
  1000}
```

and it looks  like `Outer` is a bit faster, but the `f[1, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{x, y}]` definitely looks cleaner. Results are normalized over `n^2`

[image]

Comment: [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)

Comment: `g[x, #] & /@ Flatten[Outer[List, X, Y], 1]`

Comment: Or `Flatten[Outer[g[x, #1, #2] &, X, Y]]`. `@bills` I think it needs `Sequence@#` in your expression?

Comment: `g[x, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{X, Y}]`

Comment: @belisarius That's nice!

Comment: Actually, @march's use of `Outer[]` can be simplified: `Outer[g[x, ##] &, X, Y] // Flatten`.

Comment: @J. M. SlotSequence. One of many things that could revolutionize my life.

Comment: @belisarius Care to post your comment as an answer? I want to close this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested, I'm copying the above comment as an answer:

```
g[x, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{X, Y}]
```

seems an elegant way to me

Comment: I'd like to add to this answer that `Outer` has the advantage over `g[x, ##] & @@@ Tuples[{X, Y}]` when it comes to packed arrays, since `Outer` doesn't unpack while `@@@` does.

Answer (score 1):

```
Distribute[g[x, X, Y], List]
```

> {g[x, 1, 5], g[x, 1, 6], g[x, 1, 7], g[x, 1, 8],
>     g[x, 2, 5], g[x, 2, 6], g[x, 2, 7], g[x, 2, 8],
>     g[x, 3, 5], g[x, 3, 6], g[x, 3, 7], g[x, 3, 8]}