# How-to implement iteration over a result of an iteration in a functional way

Tags: map, pure-function

I have a pure function

```
f:= #1 * #2 * #3 &;
```

Which I can invoke in a following way:

```
f[#,2,3]& /@ {1,2,3}
```

Which yields following result:

```
{6, 12, 18}
```

How could I do something like this:

```
f[#1,#2,3]& /@ {{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}
```

such that the return product would look like:

```
{{3,6,9},{6,12,18},{9,18,27}}
```

I understand there is a syntax error above. I struggle coming up with a functional solution which would avoide iteration and loops. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance.

Example based on OOP (conceptual):

```
List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
  for(int m = 1; m < 3; m++){
     product = i * m * 3;
     nums.add(product)
  }
}
System.out.println("Product: " + nums.toString());
```

Comment: If you want all combinations of possible `#1` and `#2`, use `Outer`.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85165/applying-function-to-cartesian-product-of-two-lists deals with this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the construct you are probably looking for is `Outer` (see [its documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)).

You could then define the following function to achieve what you indicated, even without using `Map`:

```
Clear[func]
func[list1_List, list2_List, factor_?NumberQ] := factor Outer[Times, list1, list2]
func[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 3]

(* Out: {{3, 6, 9}, {6, 12, 18}, {9, 18, 27}} *)
```